# Problems in hibernate CascadeType

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entity beans and join table between them as follow

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.employee")
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<EmployeeGroup> employeeGroups = new HashSet<EmployeeGroup>();
}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "messaginggroup", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "group_name") })
public class MessagingGroup implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.messaginggroup")
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<EmployeeGroup> employeeGroups = new HashSet<EmployeeGroup>();
}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_group")
@AssociationOverrides(value = {
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.messaginggroup", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "group_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "employee_id")) })
public class EmployeeGroup implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeGroupId pk = new EmployeeGroupId();
}
```

when adding and removing using my join table i use

```
public void updateMsgGroup() {
        try {
            log.debug("### Updating Messaging Group ##### ");
            MessagingGroup msgGroup = msgGroupServ.getMsgGroupByID(Long
                    .parseLong(selectedmsgGroup));
            msgGroup.setGroupName(this.catchedGroupName);

            Set<EmployeeGroup> mySet = msgGroup.getEmployeeGroups();
            for (EmployeeGroup mepGrop : mySet) {
                msgGroupServ.deleteEmpMsgGroup(mepGrop);
            }

            // msgGroup.getEmployeeGroups().clear();
            Set<EmployeeGroup> amySet = new HashSet<EmployeeGroup>();
            for (Employee newEmp : this.currentRelatedEmp) {
                EmployeeGroup empGrp = new EmployeeGroup();
                empGrp.setEmployee(newEmp);
                empGrp.setMessageGroup(msgGroup);
                empGrp.setJoinType(true);
                msgGroup.getEmployeeGroups().add(empGrp);
                amySet.add(empGrp);
                // empGroupsList.add(empGrp);
            }
            log.debug(" $$$$ Set Size $$$$     " + mySet.size());
            // msgGroup.setEmployeeGroups(mySet);
            msgGroupServ.updateMsgGroup(msgGroup);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

why setting `CascadeType` to `CascadeType.REMOVE` 
i can remove but adding doesn't work
and when setting it as `CascadeType.All`
i can add but cannot remove from db

So any idea for how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
```

SAVE_UPDATE = cascade for adding and updating elements;
ALL = cascade only add
then you must define DELETE too

reference: [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html)